# How to access other Disk(hard disk) from Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, hard-drive, ssd

I am not a expert in Ubuntu,
I have a SSD and HDD, my win and Ubuntu are dual booted in SSD.
But my HDD is not showing in other location in file section.

If anyone have a idea.

This is the result for `sudo blkid`

```
    /dev/sda5: UUID="08fa6bc0-9484-4a46-bdee-086929b78465" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="795673e7-696c-4c0f-9273-0dbfe91e0813"
    /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="LDM metadata partition" PARTUUID="d5717211-a422-11ea-afde-a45d366b6129"
    /dev/sdb2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="d5717212-a422-11ea-afde-a45d366b6129"
    /dev/sdb3: PARTLABEL="LDM data partition" PARTUUID="d5717217-a422-11ea-afde-a45d366b6129"
    /dev/sda1: LABEL="500mb" UUID="4E6ABFDF6ABFC1CF" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="624faf16-775d-4b44-8bcd-9235584dcc74"
    /dev/sda2: UUID="EE6F-DE97" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="4c7f95f1-e3a4-46f2-82bf-f9f1ccfa9d3a"
    /dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="190474af-7ba0-4615-a803-11118fcc9ead"
    /dev/sda4: UUID="04F0AAC9F0AABFF2" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="58d33869-9014-41e8-9e2a-fe94196515dc"
    /dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
```

and this is the result of sudo parted -1

```
Model: ATA KINGSTON SA400S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  472MB   471MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 2      473MB   577MB   104MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      577MB   593MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      593MB   84.5GB  83.9GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      84.5GB  120GB   35.6GB  ext4


Model: ATA WDC WD10JPVT-60A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  1066kB  1049kB               LDM metadata partition
 2      1066kB  134MB   133MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      134MB   1000GB  1000GB               LDM data partition
```

Comment: How do we know it?

Comment: Can you give me any steps to follow or link to see @Pilot6

Comment: Please add output of `sudo blkid` and `sudo parted -l` commands to your question. Please add it as text!

Comment: done @Pilot6,  what should i do next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDM partitions are not supported by Ubuntu.

If you want to use this disk with Ubuntu, you need to backup your data and create a new partition table on this disk.